# Migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, migration

I am looking for a migration tool. We want to upgrade from SharePoint Server 2007 to SharePoint 2010 in a new environment. We need to have functionality to granulary select which content to migrate and eaven select to map to new structure in the new solution.
We want to tag the content migrated. 
The migration tools we are considering are AvePoint, Axceler Davinci, Metalogix.

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing migration scenarios for a consultant firm based in Montreal. First of all, I think you have the correct thinking about how you want to get this done. Doing a SharePoint upgrade (database upgrade) usually bring your SharePoint 2007 problems over to SharePoint 2010.

Here's what we usually do :

- Define governance for the new SharePoint platform
- Define the new Information Architecture
- Implement the new Information Architecture (build sites, lists, libraries, etc.)
- Migrate the content over

Tools such as Sharegate (www.share-gate.com) can allow you to do some mapping from your old content source over to the new one.

Hopefully, this will help you!

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one+ for this, you are so correct! :)